# How can I pass a vetor element to the find command of unix?

Tags: shell, unix, find

How can I pass a array element to the find command of unix?  eg.:
I try find    tcs/*APPS[i]     but don't work

```
APPS=("av_bench" "mpeg4_decoder" "radio_sys" "vopd" "h263e" "h264dl" "sample" "sparse") 

for i in APPS
do
    DATA=$(find tcs/*APPS[i] -name log_packet_header.csv -exec bash -c 'get_data "{}"' \;)
    echo "APPS[i]"
done
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't have time to build a full answer but have you looked at xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the elements of the array.  Say:

```
for i in "${APPS[@]}"
do
    DATA=$(find tcs/"${i}" -name log_packet_header.csv -exec bash -c 'get_data "{}"' \;)
    echo "${i}"
done
```